# Kriya to get rid of anger or related emotions?

Tags: spirituality, kriyayoga

Just wanted to know if there is any kriya stated in our scriptures that can help a sadhak get rid of anger or release related emotions from the body?

I am hoping such a kriya would not need any sort of initiation from a guru.

Do cite authentic references.

Comment: Well if we can't get rid of it entirely then at least we should be able to control it or say minimize it ... @VARUN.NRAO

Comment: I think it's better to start with meditation. Simple meditation like Isha Kriya or Hamsa meditation may be useful.